# WCF RIA -joining two tables

Tags: silverlight, ria

I found a lot of explanations about this issue, but nothing that really helped me. The thing is simple. I have two tables on my dataModel: Events and TimeStamps, both have the field EntryID, which is the relation between them(the tables are in fact Views, I can't perform changes on DB, I can only query them).On my domainService, I have the created methods for getting data from each of the tables. So far, I am able to fill a dataGrid with data from only one of the tables, but what I really need is to display from both tables. In T-SQL it would be something like:

```
  Select e.EntryID,t.closed_time
  from Events e inner join TimeStamps t
  on e.EntryID=t.EntryID
```

So I want to display on my dataGrid the Entry_ID and closed_time.I appreciate your help for solving my problem

I tried a new custom class

```
    public class CustomTable
    {
        public string EntryId { get; set; }
        public int closed_time { get; set; }
    }

    public IQueryable<CustomTable> GetJoined()
    {
        return (from i in this.ObjectContext.Events                   
                join p in this.ObjectContext.TimeStamps p
                on i.Entry_ID equals p.Entry_ID
                select new CustomTable
                {
                    EntryId = i.Entry_ID,
                    closed_Time = p.Closed_TIME
                });
    }
```

This is the additional code I added by myself, I'm pretty sure something is missing, this method and the class itself were added on my service.cs

Comment: What are you trying (code)? What is the return type you are transferring across via RIA?

Comment: see additional information above-Thanks

Comment: What happens when you make a RIA call to the GetJoined() method? Assign the return value to a var first (instead of returning it immediately) and inspect it in the debugger (you can expand the results) to see that you actually get data back from your database.

Comment: At this moment, I get a compile error, the MyProject.Web.g.cs created a method: public EntityQuery<IncidentService.CustomTable> GetJoinedQuery() adn I am getting an error: Error 3 The type or namespace name 'IncidentService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: ok, I fixed previous issue, I created a new class outside the IncidentService. I am getting something else now, I will update soon, Thanks

Comment: Hi,I managed to run my project, the problem here is that I am getting the datagrid without any data.I can see the lines on it(zebra format) but they are empty and very narrow.I tried to reduce number of results to 1 and got no data at all

Comment: Well, It is working now. The problem was that I was not choosing the right parameters fro the datagrid, so I got it empty. I changed the parameters(from Entry_ID to EntryId and from Closed_TIME to closed time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final code and procedures done, do not forget to build the project after each step:

1- Opened a new class under Myproject.Web(Add-->new item-->class)

```
namespace Myproject.Web
{

    public class CustomTable
    {
        [Key]
        public string EntryId { get; set; }
        public int closed_Time { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2-Added on IncidentService.cs:

```
public IQueryable<CustomTable> GetJoined()
{
    return (from i in this.ObjectContext.Events                   
            join p in this.ObjectContext.TimeStamps p
            on i.Entry_ID equals p.Entry_ID
            select new CustomTable
            {
                EntryId = i.Entry_ID,
                closed_Time = p.Closed_TIME
            });
}
```

3-Added on Mypage.xaml.cs

```
public MyPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = _IncidentContext.CustomTables;
    _IncidentContext.Load(_IncidentContext.GetJoinedQuery());



    DataGridTextColumn entry = new DataGridTextColumn();
    entry.Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("EntryId");
    entry.Header = "Entry Id";

    DataGridTextColumn closed = new DataGridTextColumn();
    closed.Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("closed_Time");
    closed.Header = "Closed Time";

    dataGrid1.Columns.Add(entry);
    dataGrid1.Columns.Add(closed);

}
```

I hope this will help others with same issue, I spent 3 days working on this solution!!